# I need to download an excel (Microsoft Excel Worksheet (.xlsx)) file which is available in server

Tags: java, angularjs, excel

```
 $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                  'Accept': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'},

    }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.alerts = [];
        if (data.success) {
            $scope.alerts.push({type:'success', msg : data.message});
            var blob = new Blob([data.binary], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
            console.log(blob.type);      
            var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.open(objectUrl);
        }
        else {
            $scope.alerts.push({type:'danger', msg : data.message});
        }

    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.alerts.push({type:'danger', msg : 'Report failed. ' + data});
    });
```

In java side:

```
byte[] b =downloadReport();
        result.put("binary", b);
```

> method called to return byte array.

```
public byte[] downloadReport()
{
    File file = new File("D:/app/ce/excel/report/Report20151223_1133.xlsx");

    byte[] b = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try {
          FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
          fileInputStream.read(b);
          for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
                      System.out.print((char)b[i]);
           }
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                 System.out.println("File Not Found.");
                 e.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch (IOException e1) {
              System.out.println("Error Reading The File.");
               e1.printStackTrace();
     }
    return b;

}
```

> Why downloaded excel is opening with a message "Cannot open bcoz the file format or extension is not valid." Please check.
>
> Requirement is like it should downloaded with proper data.

Comment: a) You're not checking the return value of the `fileInputStream.read()` call. `read()` is not guaranteed to read all the data you ask it to read, and it will return the number of bytes it actually red. b) don't print binary data to the console - but that's not likely to cause this problem, just a lot of other ones c) don't ignore exceptions like this - you're returning a byte array with all zeros when there was an exception such as "file not found"

Comment: Any thing else .....Still the downloaded file is not opening..Thanks.

Comment: I am stuck , any help will be appreciated.